# SQL Server 2005 Alter table column not being recognized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is on a replicated table in SQL Server 2005

I used the following command:

```
ALter table dbo.apds alter column docket nvarchar(12) null
```

and it executed with no errors, everything looks clean.

Column spec shows it now has 12 (was previously set to 6) on both tables, publisher
and subscriber.

But when I try to put more than 6 characters in that column, I get the error:

> Msg 8152 lefel 16, state 13, procedure trgapdsupdate, line 5
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I can still only write 6 characters of data to that column even though it shows 12 as the 
column specification..

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: what is your old column datatype? and. What is your new column datatype? (i.e) After Alter Table Column. Can you please check your Table and mention exactly

Comment: Just try create table from the structure of the table which you have altered. Keep new table as temptable. And export your alter table values to the temptable and see the values.

Comment: The old column type was nvarchar(6) the new column type is nvarchar(12)
I am trying to put data in it like 1037-13, I can put 103713 but I cannot put 10372013 or 1037-13.

Comment: Is there a parameter or variable in trgapdsupdate that also needs its size changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> I get the error: msg 8152 lefel 16, state 13, procedure trgapdsupdate,
>   line 5 string or binary data would be truncated. The statement has
>   been terminated

So what is `trgapdsupdate`?

From the name it looks like an update trigger on the table `apds`?

Does that need to be updated to deal with the new column value? For example writing to an audit table whose definition needs to be updated.

Comment: the trgapdsupdate is from an update I tried thinking maybe my access was not recognizing the change up, so I went to mgmnt studio and tried an update to a record with more than 6 characters. Just something I was doing to troubleshoot the situation.

Comment: @user3014234 - If you tried this update in the SSMS GUI and got that error message it is definitely coming from a trigger on the table. In management studio object explorer expand the table and have a look at the triggers.

Comment: Mr. Smith, you were probably telling me and I was just to dense to fully understand, but your questions got me thinking this table is part of some transaction tracking that we do and I had not expanded that tables column spec, once I did that, we are good to go. Thank you very much, you have solved the issuee..